# Determine How far drag point is

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UIImageView and I am trying to determine when a drag is performed, how far that drag is from the origin. I currently have this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

if(CGRectContainsPoint(myimage.frame, location) == 0){

}
else
{ //user didn't tap inside image}
```

The image itself does not move, but a person can take their finger, click on the image and then drag their finger. I am just trying to determine that drag distance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to calculate distance, you need to remember the point (store it somewhere) in `touchesBegan` if the user tapped on your image.
Then in `touchesMoved` or `touchesEnd` you will be able to get current point and calculate distance to your original point.

If you need to get distance from `UIImageView` origin, you can call `[touch locationInView:myImage];`

And I suggest you to use `UIGestureRecognizer` class instead of handling touches by yourself. They are simpler to implement.